# Change column order of excel document of numpy array in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I imported `excel` data into a `numpy` array using `pandas`. I now need to change the orders of the columns.

The columns that need to be changed are ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'] to ['C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G']

But I am getting an error `DataFrame object is not callable`

```
# importing python libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# reading source excel files and storing into two DataFrames
df1 = pd.read_excel('filepath')

# reading data by row
datax = []

def getRows(excel_file, sheet_name, start_row = 1):
    excel_data = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = sheet_name, header=None)
    #print(excel_data)
    size = excel_data.shape
    #print(size)
    row_num = size[0]
    for i in range(start_row, row_num):
        data = excel_data.iloc[i].values.tolist()
        datax.append(data)
    return datax

getRows("filepath", "sheetname", 0)

a = np.array(datax)

df = pd.DataFrame(a[:,[0,1,2,4,6,9,13,14]], columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])


df2 = df(pd.DataFrame(a[:,[0,1,2,4,6,9,13,14]], columns =['C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G']))
df2.to_excel("filepath")

print(df2)
```

Comment: Change 
`df2 = df(pd.DataFrame(a[:,[0,1,2,4,6,9,13,14]], columns =['C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G']))`
to 
`df2 = pd.DataFrame(a[:,[0,1,2,4,6,9,13,14]], columns =['C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G'])`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @PeterLeimbigler. That did not change the data in the columns. The columns stayed the same, but the headers changed. I am trying to switch the data in the first df to be in the order of the second one

Comment: Sorry! I think I understand now... Instead of creating a new DataFrame from the `a` array, try manually specifying the order of the columns like this: `df2 = df['C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G'].copy()`

Comment: I got a key error @PeterLeimbigler. It says KeyError ('C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G')

Comment: I made a simple error: try double brackets! `df2 = df[['C','B','A','D','F','H','E','G']].copy()`